# Linux, monitor read rates of files

Tags: linux, throughput

I have a custom application which has a bunch of files open. I can see the file handles open by a process using "lsof" and I can see the files being accessed using "watch -d 'ls -alh'" and watching the mtime/ctime. However, I would like to see the rate of data that is being read/written to these files. IE: I need to determine if one file is being read at 100 Mbps and maxing out a disk. Subsequently, are there several files which are being written at 1 Mbps? Looking at the throughput for a specific disk isn't too useful as I need to narrow down which file is being hammered.

I'm afraid there is also a catch; ideally I need to determine this without installing any other software or writing scripts... Simply because this is one of those "very-production" systems.

Does anybody know of a way? Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `strace`. It can attach to running processes and tell you exactly what syscalls they execute and what the parameters are - with a small interpreter script, you can deduce exactly how many bytes are being read from which file handle while you watch.

Comment: That's okay, but I was hoping for a more standard command, I am quite amazed that this is not part of the standard system utilities or something.